# Can't build libcUrl with OpenSSL

Tags: curl, openssl, mingw

I'm using mingw. I downloaded OpenSSl and zlib from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html links for Windows. Change paths to openSSl and Zlib in all makefile32.m32. Try to build with **mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib** But when I got errors, I don't understand why :(

Erorrs are

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [libcurl.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `c:/curl/lib'
mingw32-make: *** [mingw32-ssl] Error 2
```

I changed makefile a bit more. added write paths to the openSSl libs. But I've got there two libs: libeay32.a and ssleay32.a. And option in makefile is  **curl_LDADD += -L$(OPENSSL_PATH)\lib\MinGW -leay32 -lssl32**. When I change -lssl32 to -lssleay32, the same error is - cannot find -lssleay32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL is not consistent with library naming, depending on how the libraries were compiled. It bit me once too. Make sure you have the files

```
libeay.a
libssl.a
libz.a
```

Or names the makefile expects. The `lib` prefix is very important here, otherwise your linker won't find it.

Comment: Oh, there where not lib-prefix in one file! It built. But now when I try to run program I've got a lots of errors like ..\lib\/libcurl.a(ssluse.o):(.text+0x121): undefined reference to

Comment: @Alecs: You're probably linking your application statically, which means that if you link your libcurl, you'll also need to link all libraries it depends on (in this case the OpenSSL libraries).

Comment: I described errors here, can you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967729/how-to-use-curl-and-openssl