# How to use cUrl and OpenSSL

Tags: curl, openssl, mingw

I downloaded everything from this page http://curl.haxx.se/download.html . Build libcurl with **mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib**, put received libcurl.a and libcurldll.a into my lib folder. I also added into my include folder all OpenSSL headers. I must mentioned, that before I build cUrl without OpenSSL, and it worked. I tried to compile with

```
g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -DUSE_SSLEAY -DUSE_OPENSSL -ID:\Workspacee\Uploader\src\openssl -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\main.o ..\src\main.cpp
```

but I received a lots of errors - here they all http://pastebin.com/YmYPu9BA

Can someone help me? What am I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6966873/256138) the lead to this one, if you link statically, the final executable will need all dependent libraries explicitely linked in. The OpenSLL code is not present in the libcurl static library.

Just add the same OpenSSL linker flags as you did when building libcurl.

Comment: thanks! And can you advice some articles about linking to read, because I know about linking, differences between static and dynamic libraries and linking, how to use them in proper way just a bit? If no will read what google show =)

Comment: I added them, it has built, no errors, but application don't run, it's terminated, without any explanation :(

Comment: please take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013708/weird-things-with-libcurl-and-openssl)