# Weird things with libCurl and OpenSSL

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, mingw, libcurl

It's me again. I just can't understand, why it goes that way!

I downloaded compiled static libs of OpenSSL, [from here](http://www.shininglightpro.com/download/Win32OpenSSL-1_0_0d.exe), this link is on the official cUrl site in Download page. I downloaded Zlib and compiled them, then I compiled libcurl with

```
mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib
```

I changed in all makefile.m32 pathes to the Zlib and OpenSSL files. All went fine, I recieved libcurl.a and libcurldll.a. I added into lib folder of my project libcurl.a and libeay32.a, libssleay32.a and libz.a.
I built project - it says that everything is fine. I run - and it just terminated. I'm using MinGW and Eclipse.

It is compiled with this:

```
g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\main.o ..\src\main.cpp

g++ -L..\lib -oYTUploader.exe src\main.o -lcurl -lws2_32 -lwldap32 -leay32 -lssleay32 -lz
```

I run DependencyWalker, and it says that it's missing ieshims.dll, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll. But WHY? Why it want OpenSSL dll, I'm using static linking! I built static libCurl library, with static libs of OpenSSL. About ieshims.dll I also can't get why it needs it!
Help, please, I have no idea what is wrong! I compiled cUrl according to the instruction, everything should be fine..

Comment: Try [this download](http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.21.7-devel-mingw32.zip) which is referenced on the curl website above yours, under "Win32 - generic".

Comment: BTW, although SO is a place you can ask these questions, you are better off asking either on the curl or mingw users mailing lists or forums.

Comment: @rubenvb: I've tried, I get undefined references erorrs :( And I've mailed today to curl-library-mailing-list

Comment: Alecs: Sorry to hear that. I'm out of ideas :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The openssl-libs you link against seem to be import-libraries. That means they only contain the information your code needs to call functions and then load and call the corresponding functions from the dll.

So the problem is: although you link to static libs, the libs then load and use dynamic dlls. They are no "real" static libs.

One solution is getting other libs (or compile them yourself), or even easier: you just copy the dlls into the directory where your .exe resides and you should be fine.

Comment: And do you know where can I get OpenSSL static libs? And how can I recognize that the libs are "real" static libs?

Answer (score 0):

Use the configure script to tell ld where openssl has installed the files. the defaults are as follows:

```
tar -zxf curl-7.33.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.33.0
./configure --prefix=/opt/curlssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --enable-http --enable-ftp LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/ssl/lib CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/ssl/include

make
make install
```